# EditText on different devices or emulator is in a deferent position

Tags: android, android-edittext, alignment

I use the code below for a popup alert box with a `EditText` in it. I am using margin to align the `EditText` in the code below. The problem is the margin numbers that I use for the one device or emulator will be off on an other device or emulator. if I align one device correctly, it will look off on the other device. Any help is appreciated.

```
AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new      AlertDialog.Builder(ExpenseSheet.this);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(85, 0, 50, 0);
    // Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(ExpenseSheet.this);
    //FOCUSING ON POPUP WINDOW TEXT
    input.requestFocus();
    layout.addView(input, params);

    // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    //limiting the amount of characters
    input.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8)});
    aBuilder.setView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using hard-coded numbers for margin which represent pixels by default. this pixel count can get converted to a longer or shorter actual length on devices depending upon their screen density.

you should try multiplying these values with screen density in order to make them look constant across devices of various screen densities.

**example:**

```
 final DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 final float screenDensity = metrics.density;
 double mWidth = 25 * screenDensity;// constant width across densities
 double mHeight = 30 * screenDensity;// constant height across densities
```

now you can use such variables instead of hard-coded values to get uniform effect across various screen densities.

Comment: I pasted your code and context is red. context is under a compiler error.

Comment: in your case `context` will be replaced by `ExpenseSheet.this` , as that's your activity and in-turn context. I suggest you to read more about context.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I'm just curious, what kind of incentive do you guys actually get for helping people out?